# code formatting lost after edit, revert would not fix it

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, code-formatting

I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499197/895810) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34499197/895810), (changed "unicode" to "str") however when I saved the edit, the code formatting was lost. I quickly reverted the edit, however the code formatting was still lost after reverting. I cannot seem to get the answer to display this piece of the answer correctly.

1. Help!
2. Why did the revert to the original answer cause the formatting to be lost?

This is the how the code text in the answer is now displayed:
[image]

which should look like:
[image]

The answer used to look like ([archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20221011021541/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498417/import-text-file-from-geonames-using-pandas-python)):

[image: Screenshot of an archive of the answer being asked about showing the code in code format]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I restored the code formatting in the answer. The code appeared to be specifically in reference to point #2, so I left it indented under that item. It wasn't previously indented. In fact, the numbered list wasn't previously rendered as a numbered list. In the original render, those are just text in `<p>` paragraphs with text that starts with a number.

The reason that rolling it back was not sufficient to restore the code formatting is because older versions are kept as Markdown, not as rendered HTML. The current version of the post is rendered into HTML when saved and that rendered HTML is what's served until a new version is current. The version to which you rolled it back was from 2015. That version used to be parsed by a completely different Markdown parser, which didn't do things quite the same as the current CommonMark Markdown parser. When you rolled it back, the Markdown from that version was rendered using the current CommonMark Markdown parser, resulting in a different HTML render.